# In-cylinder combustion pressure

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have pressure data with respect to crank angle and I want to convert it into Sound pressure level with respect to frequency. Please suggest any known procedure .Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SP.SE!  You will need some time-reference to do that. Do you have the time instants at which the crank angle / pressure information were taken?

Comment: Yes i do. I am trying to achieve combustion noise level from pressure data. after conducting FFT, how to apply A-weighting and U-filter?

Comment: Do you have more insights to update your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the engine speed $N$ is constant, given in RPM (Revolution per minute), with an angular sampling of $\alpha$, you should convert it into a sampling interval:

$$ \Delta t = \frac{\alpha}{6N}\,.$$

The sampling frequency in Hertz is the inverse.

If the pressure data $P$ is given in bars, you should convert it to the SI unit in Pascals (about $10^{−5}$ bars) to get an absolute sound pressure. The [Sound Pressure Level (SPL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level) is a logarithmic ratio of the absolute sound pressure and a reference level, depending on the application.

Be aware that crank angle sampling is often far for uniform, and at certain speeds the angular sampling is too high to capture phenomena without aliasing.

Comment: My aim is to determine peak noise level. For this purpose I have converted crank angle into time data, pressure into SPL data and then conducted FFT analysis to obtain peaks in dB. But the plot doesn't quite look like a typical SPL vs Hz curve. Also how to apply filters using Matlab. I want to apply A and CAV filter to obtain precise data.Please suggest me the way to achieve this using Matlab or excel. Thank you.

Comment: I did in the past an approximate Matlab implementation of the AVL noisemeter, based on CA sampled data. The information I  had on the AVL filter was quite shallow.

Comment: I am working on the same now. Accuracy is not very crucial at this point of time for me. I should be able to understand how we apply filters and get an approximate number. Your inputs from your previous work would be very helpful to me

Comment: The procedure i mentioned above, is it correct? Should i convert pressure into SPL before conducting FFT or after? Any step-wise procedure ?

Comment: I believe you ought to define more precisely what is your peak energy. The A filter is common, I don't know about the CAV one. Do you have them in time or frequency domain? They can be implemented in frequency, and the scalings can be put aside first and added as constants in dB